# android studio 4 sdk manager window doesn't open and file-> settings window doesn't open also

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

Android studio 4 sdk manager window doesn't open and **file-> settings window** doesn't open also.
In previous versions it was working but i (sorry to do that) take the decision to download the new package V4 and install it rather than working with the updates which i already did, anyway in the new installation the updates is working normally but some functions do not work:
SDK manager window

**File-> settings window**

**Flutter Dart devtools**

I searched a lot and downloaded the sdk tools and replaced the existing folder but nothing changed, I run **flutter doctor --android-licenses**  but still nothing.
It seems it is not a common problem as i search before and still can't find a solution, please help me.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to uninstall whole android studio

**step 1**: close Android Studio

**step 2**: delete the environment directory ".AndroidStudio4.0" (the latest one)
(or you could just modify the directory name to keep it in case)

the directory will be in

C:\Users{username}\.AndroidStudio4.0  (windows)

Users/{username}/Librqry/Application Support/AndroidStudio4.0 (mac)

**step 3**: open Android Studio (you could load the settings of the last version)

Android Studio will find that you don't have the ".AndroidStudio4.0 " directory and create a new one for you

**Notice:**
your setting will be reset unless you keep the last version directory to let you load

Comment: I had the same issue with 4.1, and this resolved my issue, however the Windows location of this folder was 
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

Answer (score 0):

After alot of trials and search i just made clean uninstall.
Uninstall android studio and all its settings and related files:
C:\Users%username%\AppData\local and delete Android, .android, .AndroidStudio(#version-number) and also .gradle
C:\Programfiles/android and delete sdk
C:\Users%username%\AppData\Roaming and delete the JetBrains directory

then install new version of android studio with new settings.